# Self Inverse in Integral Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to show that if R is an integral domain and it has unity then the only elements of R which are inverse to itself are 1 and -1 (with respect to multiplication). But I don't know where to start. Can anyone help? Thanks..

Comment: Write it in the form of an equation rather than in the form of an English phrase.

Comment: More generally, any polynomial has number of roots bounded by its degree.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint:
$$(x+1)(x-1)=x^2-1.$$